# Have disabled textarea show entire text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a disabled `textarea` that contains an unknown amount of text because it is used with comments. For example,

```
<textarea class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" disabled="true">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tortor sapien, convallis id molestie at, egestas et ex. Mauris sagittis lorem ut nunc commodo scelerisque. Sed congue, est in mattis vulputate, mi mauris facilisis lorem, in volutpat mi urna ac libero. Ut tempus nulla sed massa ullamcorper aliquam. Nullam laoreet purus vel mi feugiat, luctus vestibulum nunc vestibulum. Nulla lacinia sapien eu velit semper tristique et eu est. Aliquam sit amet facilisis mi. Nullam nec ullamcorper orci, auctor accumsan nibh. Morbi quis lacus velit. Nullam aliquet turpis quam, in pharetra lacus sodales at. Suspendisse id neque sed dui commodo aliquet. Vivamus blandit eleifend interdum. Morbi ac odio nulla. Mauris cursus ultrices ex, in placerat risus. Ut dictum justo a magna ornare pharetra.
</textarea>
```

The problem is that because the `textarea` is disabled it is not very clear to users that they can scroll using the arrows when using IE. The solution that I would like to do is have all of the text show so there is not a need to scroll. I have not been able to find a way to force the `textarea` to blow out all of the way.

How can I have all of the text show in the text box? Javascript and jQuery are open for use but it will need to work across all browsers include mobile devices and IE9.

Comment: Will the textarea be `enabled` at any point? Does it need to be a textarea?

Comment: No it will always be disabled as we do not allow editing of the comment for compliance reasons. It does not have to be a text area but will need to have the same look/feel in order to flow with my companies UX guidelines. I did not even think about putting it inside of a `p` or anything like that. Great thinking!

Comment: There are plugins to make this work, alternatively you can style a div to look like a textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place text into a `div` and style it like a `textarea` with CSS.

Comment: The only issue I am having with this is when a user adds a break/enter there is not a way for me to show that. I used `white-space: pre-wrap;` to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS:

```
textarea {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
```

Simple :). And by the way, a shorter version would be, for a disabled textarea, is this:

```
<textarea disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change the height of the textarea using a jQuery plugin like this one (or similar):
http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/textarea-expander/index.html

by the way, its `disabled="disabled"`, and not `disabled="true"`.